# Set ViewController as Delegate of another UIView Class

Tags: ios, uiview

Lets say I have 2 classes.

One is the well known ViewController (that is set to be the custom class of the first scene in the Interface Builder).

And another class, lets call it **B**, that I created to draw something inside another view that is a sub view of the main view.

Since I have to get notified whenever some values changes in the sub view in order to do some things in the view controller, I decided to use the ***delegate pattern***.

So I set up the protocol in the **B** class, but now I have to link the delegate to the **view controlle**r class. How can I manage to get the view controller class from the class B?

By the way I instantiate some things using  `override function willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?)` in **B**. Can I maybe use newSuperView to get the view controller?

I know it is not the best approach since it may break the MVC Pattern, but I don't know which better way to do this.

To get an idea of what I mean you can look at the image.
[image]

Comment: use `notificationcenter` as good practice.

Comment: Normally, in `viewDidLoad` you would set `self.someSubView.delegate = self`